# Opening a port to the world on AWS not working

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, port, rasa

I am having trouble accessing a service that is running in a docker container (port 5005) from the internet over TCP.

The server is a ubuntu AWS ec2 instance with port 5005 open in the security group (both v4 and v6 addressing)

[image: AWS Inbound Security Settings]

The docker processes are running fine, appearing to map the port from inside its container to the ec2 instance.

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-5-89:~$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                       NAMES
71e620ea2969   rasa/rasa-sdk:latest    "./entrypoint.sh sta…"   15 minutes ago   Up 15 minutes   0.0.0.0:5055->5055/tcp, :::5055->5055/tcp   emma_action_server_1
533010182ca7   rasa/rasa:latest-full   "rasa run --enable-a…"   15 minutes ago   Up 15 minutes   0.0.0.0:5005->5005/tcp, :::5005->5005/tcp   emma_rasa_1
```

(yes, 5005 and 5055 are both valid ports and not a typo - but only 5005 should be exposed to the ec2 instance and up through the firewall out to the web.
ufw appears to be signalling the port fine.

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
5005/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
5005                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
5005/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
5005 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

and the ec2 instance appears to be listening fine:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-5-89:~$ sudo netstat -plunta | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      561/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5055            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6473/docker-proxy   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5005            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6451/docker-proxy   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      810/sshd: /usr/sbin 
tcp6       0      0 :::5055                 :::*                    LISTEN      6480/docker-proxy   
tcp6       0      0 :::5005                 :::*                    LISTEN      6458/docker-proxy   
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      810/sshd: /usr/sbin
```

Yet, when I try accessing *public.IP.address*:5005 on any online port checking tool - it says the port is closed. When I actually try to make a POST request via postman - I get ETIMEDOUT which Im not sure is another way to say its closed, or infact, its just a timeout... but when I make the same POST request on the server, using local addressing, it works fine.

This works locally on ec2 (outside of container):

```
curl -XPOST localhost:5005/webhooks/rest/webhook -d '{"message":"hi"}'
```

this doesnt work - ETIMEOUT:

```
curl -XPOST publicIPAddressHere:5005/webhooks/rest/webhook -d '{"message":"hi"}'
```

The ACL and Network appear to be setup correctly also.

[image: ACL1]

[image: ACL2]

When I run the reachability analyser, it works - but thats obviously coming from inside the network from the private IP address... 172... so the issue is clearly exposing the port to the world.

Comment: did you try tracing the route from your physical pc to amazon ec2 instance, sudo traceroute -T --tcp -p 5005 public_ip_here

Comment: I use online port checking tools - Both tools that I've tried told me the port is closed to the public..

Comment: (which, I take it, can mean either the port is not being allowed - very hard to believe given the configuration checking out fine) or the service for some reason is not responding in a timely manner from outside the server (only from inside the the container to the server hosting it)

Comment: do you have any custom Network ACLs  set up? Try the reachability analyzer as the screenshot suggests

Comment: @SathyajithBhat - the reachability analyser says its visible from one instance to another on that port.....Destination

i-0f996b5e5fb48e1f6 (rasax86)
Inbound header
Destination address
172.31.xx.xx/32

Destination port range
5005-5005

Protocol
TCP

Source address
172.31.xx.xx/32

Source port range
0-65535

Comment: I should say - thats the private IP - when i use the public IP as the destination - its unreachable.

Comment: Updated question to show that the ACL appears setup correctly also

Comment: can you take a screenshot of the reachability analyzer when it fails? it should tell you why its failing. Is there a Loadbalancer infront of the instance?

Comment: It doesnt fail.... i can only use amazon ec2 instances to try to reach the service and aws uses the internal private ip address of the target server - not the public ip - so i cant use the reachability to test the public ip - which is where i am having the issue. No Load Balancer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working by creating a fresh ec2 instance on its own VPC/ACL with the same configuration as above.

Not really an answer as it is a work-around - gremlins in the system.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).